# Listview if statement

Tags: asp.net

I have this code in my listview:

```
<td>
<asp:TextBox ID="Used_For_Neighborhood_AnalysisTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("[Used For Neighborhood Analysis]") %>' /> 
</td>
```

I would like to check if this value equals Yes then make it --Yes-- in bold.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    .myYes { font-weight: bold; }
</style>

<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("[Used For Neighborhood Analysis]").ToString()) ? "--Yes--" : "" %>'
    CssClass='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("[Used For Neighborhood Analysis]").ToString()) ? "myYes" : "" %>'>
</asp:TextBox>
```

You want to use [Eval](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/06/29/how-asp-net-databinding-deals-with-eval-and-bind-statements.aspx). Otherwise, you will have to bind inside OnItemDataBound.

For a good practice, avoid space in Column name.